# Calculate axis tick locations based on data in faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have an issue where I would like to calculate locations of y-axis labels in a large plot mad with `facet_grid()`. Let me show you what I mean using the `mpg` dataset.

```
require(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hwy)) +
  facet_grid(drv ~ class, scales = "free")
```

[image]

You will notice that both axes use variable numbers of labels. Ignoring problems with the x-axis, I am interested in labelling only three values on the y-axis: 0, half of max value, and max value. It makes sense in my use-case, so here is what I tried.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hwy)) +
  facet_grid(drv ~ class, scales = "free") +
  geom_blank(aes(y = 0)) +                                 # extends y-axis to 0
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1)), # prevents ggplot2 from extending beyond y = 0
                     n.breaks = 3)                         # Three axis labels, please.
```

[image]

The plot correctly starts at y = 0 and labels it correctly. However, remaining labels are poorly assigned, and have labels `n = 2` and `n = 4` instead of `n = 3` for some reason.

If I could only directly calculate the label positions!

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hwy)) +
  facet_grid(drv ~ class, scales = "free") +
  geom_blank(aes(y = 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1)),
                     n.breaks = 3,
                     breaks = c(0, 0.5*max(hwy), 1*max(hwy))) # Maybe these formulas works?
```

```
Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'hwy' not found
```

I believe providing break points by this way should work, but that my syntax is bad. How do I access and work with the data underlying the plot? Alternatively, if this doesn't work, can I manually specify y-axis labels for each row of panels?

I could really use some assistance here, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want custom rules for breaks, the easiest thing is to use a function implementing those rules given the (panel) limits.

Below an example for labeling 0, the max and half-max.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hwy)) +
  facet_grid(drv ~ class, scales = "free") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1)),
                     limits = c(0, NA), # <- fixed min, flexible max. replaces geom_blank
                     breaks = function(x){c(x[1], mean(x), x[2])})
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution teunbrand. The problem is the overlapping of max value from row one and the min value of row two. Do you see a solution to overcome this overlapping?

Comment: You could place the panels further apart with `theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(10, "pt"))`.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but it seems to work on the x-axis maximum instead of the data maximum. I solved it by adjusting the values to the expansion of 1.1: ```breaks = function(x){c(x[1]/1.1, mean(x)/1.1, x[2]/1.1)})```. This positions the labels correctly at the half-maximum value and at the maximum value, which combined with expansion() also avoids overlapping with the next panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `scales free`: Do you get then what you desire?

```
require(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hwy)) +
  facet_grid(drv ~ class)
```

[image]